# Count y and z at end of a word

Tags: java

This is the problem: Given a string, count the number of words ending in 'y' or 'z' -- so the 'y' in "heavy" and the 'z' in "fez" count, but not the 'y' in "yellow" (not case sensitive). We'll say that a y or z is at the end of a word if there is not an alphabetic letter immediately following it. (Note: Character.isLetter(char) tests if a char is an alphabetic letter.)

```
countYZ("fez day") → 2
countYZ("day fez") → 2
countYZ("day fyyyz") → 2
```

This is my code:

```
public int countYZ(String str) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
  if (Character.isLetter(i) && (Character.isLetter(i+1)==false || i+1==str.length()) && (Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i))=='y' || Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i))=='z')){
  count++;
  }
  }
  return count;
}
```

I know it's messy, but I'm just trying to figure out why it's not working right now. It returns "0" each run through. In the if statement, I'm checking for: is i a letter? is i+1 a letter or the end of the string? and finally if i is 'y' or 'z'. Appreciate the help!

Comment: You are running your checks on "int" (`i` variable) instead of i'th letter

Comment: If we assume that words are delimited by a "space" then I would just split the string at every occurence of a "space" then just iterate over the array and check just the last letter. It would reduce the number of iterations.

Comment: I think it should be `Character(isLetter(str.charAt(i)))` instead of `Character(isLetter(i))` - and same for `Character(isLetter(str.charAt(i+1)))` (but this will throw an exception if `i == str.length()` so you have to change the evaulation order.

Comment: How about splittint the string at the ' ' and then checking how many substrings end on 'z' or 'y' --> Divide et impera!

Comment: I forgot to mention - if the character after the y or z is anything BUT a letter, then it counts as a string separator

Comment: I have found the solution, as lejlot and d-stroyer pointed out ! I was mistakingly checking the character at the int i instead. Thank you all for your input

Comment: could you provide your expectations for the input "why6oz^buzz"? As "6" and "^" are no letters they would also be treated as boundaries.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a regex:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public int countYZ(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[yz](?!\\p{L})", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(str);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        count++;
    } 
    return count;
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
[yz]      # Match the letter y or z
(?!\p{L}) # Assert that no letter follows after that
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with what a regex is quite yet!

Comment: Can't you return `regexMatcher.groupCount()`?

Comment: @0x90: I don't think so. [`.groupCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount%28%29) returns the number of capturing groups in a pattern, not the number of regex matches in a string.

Comment: Does your regex solution comply with the requirement "We'll say that a y or z is at the end of a word if there is not an alphabetic letter immediately following it"? The test by isLetter accepts all unicode letters, I'm not sure if the regex finds the correct word boundaries.

Comment: @mschenk74: I've just read the OP's comment as to what constitutes a word boundary for him. Will edit.

Comment: I suggest the regex "\\b\\w*(Z|Y)\\b"

Answer (score 3):

Use `split()` and `endsWith()`

```
public static int countYZ(String str) {
        int count = 0;
        String temp[] = str.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            if (temp[i].trim().endsWith("y") || temp[i].trim().endsWith("z"))
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

**Output:** for all your cases as required

```
countYZ("fez day") → 2
countYZ("day fez") → 2
countYZ("day fyyyz") → 2
```

Comment: Can you explain the syntax with temp[i].trim()? From what I understand you made an array with elements that were separated with a space, but is the trim for the extra space that's tacked onto each element? Thank you as well

Comment: @xheyhenry yes you can use without `trim()` as i have splited the string with space, so here `trim()` has nothing special ! so you can also use `if (temp[i].endsWith("y") || temp[i].endsWith("z"))`.

Comment: This solution doesn't comply with the definition of word boundary in the question.

Answer (score 2):

try this fix

```
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if ((Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i)) == 'y' || Character
                .toLowerCase(str.charAt(i)) == 'z')
                && i == str.length() - 1
                || !Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i + 1))) {
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
public class CountXY {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static int countXY(String str){
        int count = 0;
        String strSplit[] = str.split(" ");
        for(String i:strSplit){
            if(i.endsWith("y")||i.endsWith("z")||i.endsWith("Y")||i.endsWith("Z")){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;   
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str = "Abcy Asdz z z z y y y yyu ZZ Y ";
        System.out.println("Count::"+countXY(str));
    }

}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't comply with the definition of word boundary in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int countYZ(String str) {
        String[] array = str.split("[^a-zA-Z]");
        int count = 0;
        for (String s : array) {
            if (s.toLowerCase().trim().endsWith("y") || s.toLowerCase().trim().endsWith("z"))
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(countYZ("abcxzy"));
}

public static int countYZ(String str) {
    int countYandZ=0;
    String[] arr=str.split(" ");
    for (String i:arr){
        if(("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(i.charAt(i.length()-1))))||("Z".equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(i.charAt(i.length()-1))))){
              countYandZ++;
        }
    }
    return countYandZ;
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't comply with the definition of word boundary in the question.

Comment: @mschenk74 It was a mistake, thanks for point me out. Corrected

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because following two conditions

Character.isLetter(i) --> here you are checking isLetter for the i which is int

(Character.isLetter(i+1)==false -> it will cause indexout of error

Please check following I have check its working fine, its just modified version of your code

```
public class FirstClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String string="fez day";
          int count = 0;
         String[] strcheck = string.split(" "); 
         for (String str : strcheck) {
          if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(str.length()-1)) &&(Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(str.length()-1))=='y' || Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(str.length()-1))=='z')){
              count++;
          }
         }
          System.out.println(count);
        }
}
```

Hope this will help, Good Luck

Comment: This solution doesn't comply with the definition of word boundary in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done:

```
public int countYZ(String str) {
      //Initialize a return integer
      int ret = 0;
      //If it has at least 2 characters, we check both ends to see how many matching instances we have.
      if (str.length() >= 2)
      {
        if (!Character.isLetter(str.charAt(1)) && (str.charAt(0) == 'y' || str.charAt(0) == 'Y' || str.charAt(0) == 'z' || str.charAt(0) == 'Z')) 
        {
          ret++;
        }
        if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(str.length() - 2)) && (str.charAt(str.length()-1) == 'y' || str.charAt(str.length()-1) == 'Y' || str.charAt(str.length()-1) == 'z' || str.charAt(str.length()-1) == 'Z')) 
        {
          ret++;
        }
      }
      //If it has more than 3 characters, we check the middle using a for loop.
      if (str.length() >= 3)
      {
        for (int i = 2; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
          char testOne = str.charAt(i-2);
          char testTwo = str.charAt(i-1);
          char testThree = str.charAt(i);
          //if the first char is a letter, second is a "YZyz" char, and the third is not a letter, we increment ret by 1.
          if (Character.isLetter(testOne) && (testTwo == 'y' || testTwo == 'Y' || testTwo == 'z' || testTwo == 'Z') && (!Character.isLetter(testThree)))
          {
            ret++;
          }
        }
      }
      return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public  int countYZ(String str) {
    int count=0;

    if ( str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == 'z'||
         str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == 'y'|| 
         str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == 'Z'||
         str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == 'Y' ) {
         count += 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if ( i > 0 ) {
            if ( !( Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)) ) ) {

                if ( str.charAt(i - 1) == 'y' ||
                     str.charAt(i - 1) == 'z' ||
                     str.charAt(i - 1) == 'Y' ||
                     str.charAt(i - 1) == 'Z' ) {
                    count += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This allows the words to be separated by anything other than a letter. whitespace, numbers, etc.

```
public int countYZ(String str) {
  int count = 0;
  String newStr = str.toLowerCase();
  for (int i =0; i < newStr.length(); i++){
    if (!Character.isLetter(newStr.charAt(i))){
      if (i > 0 && (newStr.charAt(i-1) == 'y' || newStr.charAt(i-1) == 'z'))
        count++;
    }
  }
  if (newStr.charAt(str.length()-1) == 'z' || newStr.charAt(str.length()-1) == 'y')
    count++;
  return count;
}
```

Comment: This allows the words to be separated by anything other than a letter. whitespace, numbers, etc.